# how to parse xml into java object?

Tags: dom, xsd, xml-parsing, sax

Hi i have an xml in the following format generated from a web service.

```
<root>
   <item>
       <name>test</name>
       <description>test description</description>
       <link>http://xxx</link>
   </item>
</root>
```

I read the file

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());
```

now that I have doc, how would i get the  and   for each

and put it into a object call Item

```
public class Item {
      private final String name;
      private final String desc;
      private final String link;


      public Item(final String name, final String desc, final String link) {
           super();
           this.name = name;
           this.desc = desc;
           this.link = link;
      }

      // ... getters for name and desc
  }
```

I look at examples of dom element but they seem confusing. Whats the most easiest/efficent way to parse XML into java object. Can i get an example?

Using xstream works.

I did

```
final XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xstream.alias("root", LineItem.class);
xstream.aliasField("name", Item.class, "name");
xstream.aliasField("description", Item.class, "desc");
xstream.aliasField("link", Item.class, "link");
xstream.fromXml(xml);
```

Comment: which programming language you are using? If java, you can use JAXB, here is a link for good example? http://www.javabeat.net/articles/14-java-60-features-part-2-pluggable-annotation-proce-3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) can parse xml to java objects. XML need not to be created by XStream.

Example Code is [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)

Hope this would help you.

Comment: thanks , "provided you used it to generate xml." but i am getting xml from another source generated via regular dom parser written by someone else. So I am not generating xml but rather reading and converting them